# spark concurrent task via Futures thread limits?

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, future

I tried starting spark tasks from different threads so they'd execute concurrently.
According to docs all one needs to do is start the task from a different Thread.

The issue was I had some method in Zeppelin that did some work, which had some finishing stages, which where handled by few sometimes just one worker. Since I had to do the same thing multiple times on different data, I thought I get better utilization if there is more work from future tasks, rather than waiting for one task to completely finishing before issueing the next.

What did I do?

```
val sem = new Semaphore(8)
(1 to x).map... {
   sem.aquire
   Future { doWork(data(x)) }.onComplete(println(_)
}
```

This did execute and eventually do the work but the spark UI never showed more than two active Tasks.

I tried different configurations.
Usually 7 cores per executor and 2-6 executors. Input Data was reduced in partition count so I'd get only very few executors per task. I wanted spare ones.
Nothing I tried seemed to change that only ever 2 Active Tasks were visible in SparkUI.

Setup was AWS EMR, spark 2.3.0 (emr default FAIR scheduling), Zeppelin for executing the code.
I started all the code via Scala Futures from the SparkSession in Zeppelin interpreter.

**Are there any scala settings that limit the Threads the Futures execute on to two?**
**Is there any Spark setting that limits concurrent execution to maybe 2 active tasks, or is it a limitation of Spark UI?**

Comment: I would strongly suggest to keep things simple and let Spark handle concurrency for you. It's a fairly mature system for distributed computation.

Comment: If I don't hand it tasks to execute concurrently, it cannot do anything other than execute them serially. Yes it can split the work in each stage and do parts in parallel, but it will not start any tasks from the next job if it does not know about them. There are things that just cannot be done in parallel like when you coalesce to few or just one partition because you don't want a million output files, that take forever in a S3 list operation.